# Custom suffix in Angular class names

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

Is it possible to configure an Angular 7 (with CLI 7.x) project to use class name suffixes other than the default ones?

More specifically, for classes that represent dialog boxes, I want to use `Dialog` in the end, and not `DialogComponent`, which is unnecessarily long. And for classes that represent pages I want to use `Page`, and not `PageComponent`.

**examples:**

- use `LoginDialog` instead of `LoginDialogComponent`
- use `MainPage` instead of `MainPageComponent`

---

Simple renaming isn't possible, due to the `tslint` rules preset within Angular.

Comment: Did you try just... renaming them? What happened? The naming convention is just [style guidance](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-03).

Comment: The tslint configuration won't let it. The specific rules are not in the project, they are buried somewhere inside Angular.

Comment: Please put that context in the question.

Comment: I'm thinking of using a `Dialog` suffix too. What did you end up naming your file though? `login-dialog.ts|html` or `login-dialog.component.ts|html` or `login.dialog.ts|html`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open `tslint.json` in the root of your project and update a `component-class-suffix` property:

```
{
  ...
  "component-class-suffix": [true, "Component", "View"]
  ...
}
```

Please notice Component should stay there if you want the default suffix to still be valid.

Answer (score 19):

Before Angular 11, linting was done using **TSLint**. TSlint has been deprecated and **ESLint** is now used.

In `.eslintrc.js` file - In `IONIC` and `Angular <= v11` projects, Components can be created with a Page suffix to distinguish pages from 'components' used in pages.   The following `rule` adds Page as a known suffix.

```
"overrides": [{
    "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-class-suffix": [
            "warn":,
            {
                "suffixes": ["Component", "Page"],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Comment: As of angular 9, you can also use the --type option in conjection with the above to change the file name from *.component.ts to *.{type}.ts, ex login.dialog.ts (LoginDialog)

Answer (score -2):

You can edit `tslint.json`, and use the following rule:

```
"component-class-suffix": false
```

This will prevent any linting errors

Comment: You could also add `Dialog` specifically as an option, see http://codelyzer.com/rules/component-class-suffix/

Comment: @jonrsharpe Excellent, got it working with `"component-class-suffix": [true, "Component", "Dialog"]`. You should make this into an answer, as it is better than the original answer here ;)